# Adding contents of an int array together in the form of a method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

Full Question: Make a method that can be called upon which adds the contents of an int array and prints to the command line.

Issue: Calling on the method isn't working

What I've tried: Changing the format of the way I call upon the method and changing the structure of the "public static int sum(int myArray[])" line.

```
public class LabArray2 {
    int numbers[ ] = {12,15,67,18,29,40,23,4,59,5};

    public void main(String[] args){
        int total;
        total = sum(numbers[]);

    }


    public static int sum(int myArray[])
    {
        int accumulator = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            accumulator += myArray[i];
        }
        return accumulator;
    }

}
```

I am still new to the site and have referred to the t's & c's regarding posts. Please do not negative if you find the question to not be challenging. I am new to programming and hope to progress.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public void main(String[] args){` isn't the proper signature for the main entry point for a Java program.

Try changing it to `public static void main(String[] args)` instead.

Take a look at [A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) for more details.

`total = sum(numbers[]);` is not valid syntax, instead, you should be using `total = sum(numbers);`

You will now find `int numbers[] = {12, 15, 67, 18, 29, 40, 23, 4, 59, 5};` can no longer be reference from the `main` method.

You have two choices, you can make it `static`, or you can make it a local variable within the `main` method.  Personally, I prefer the latter.

You are also not printing the results...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int numbers[] = {12, 15, 67, 18, 29, 40, 23, 4, 59, 5};
    int total;
    total = sum(numbers);
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
}
```

Comment: This was one of the other things I've tried to get this working, but the same issue applies. I forgot to change it back. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm discovering the stresses of programming! Perhaps the same stresses that resulted in you becoming Mad. Who knows...

Comment: Programming didn't make me crazy, the industry did that ;)

Answer (score 0):

The array must be made static so that it can be accessed by the static main method:

```
static int numbers[] = {12,15,67,18,29,40,23,4,59,5};
```

or better yet place it within the main method if it is not accessed elsewhere:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int numbers[ ] = {12,15,67,18,29,40,23,4,59,5};
    int total;
    total = sum(numbers);
}
```

Comment: I'm still left with the error:
"java: '.class' expected" 

On this line:         total = sum(numbers[]);